# What are HP and MP in this context?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, automata

From Kozen's Automata and Computability, 3ed, lecture 32 p. 328:
[image: a]

What are HP and MP in this context?  I tried looking around and this [text](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4820/2014sp/notes/kozen-computability-sp13.pdf) says:

[image: bb]

How did the halting problem and membership problem become regular expression?  I am so loss here.

Comment: “r.e.” stands for “recursively enumerable.”

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.

Comment: Also, for future reference, "c.e." does not stand for "context-free expression".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both HP and MP are *decision problems*, namely sets of *instances* that you can think of as descriptive strings. For example,

HP is a collection of pairs $M, x$ where $M$ is the description of a Turing Machine (think of a listing) and $x$ is an input to that machine. An instance is such a pair and a pair is in the set HP if the machine described by $M$ eventually halts when started on input $x$,

and, similarly

MP is a collection of pairs $M, x$ as above and an instance of MP is in the set MP if the machine described by $M$ eventually halts in an accept state when started on input $x$.

---

In simple terms, HP is about programs and inputs and answers "Does this program halt on this input?" and MP answers "Does this program accept this input?"

The octothorpe (the # symbol) is just a separator so we know where $M$ ends and $x$ starts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight.  Let me digest this.